# How to show Bootstrap table with sort icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am new to Bootstrap, i have a requirement to show a table with sort up and down arrow near to title of the table. This is my table structure

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>#</b>  <i class='icon-arrow-up'></i><i class='icon-arrow-down'></th> **// tried** 
            <th ><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Email</b></th>
            <th><b>Team</b></th>
            <th ><b>Role</b></th>
            <th ><b>Timezone</b></th>
            <th><b>Connections</b></th>
            <th><b># Posts available</b></th>
            <th><b>Last Login</b></th>
            <th><b>Posts</b></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to display sort up/down arrows similar to the following image. 
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As is you have no javascript to do the sorting so any icon would be completely static.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr thanks for the quick reply. I have tried <i class='icon-arrow-down'> with <th> tag but its not showing any arrows.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could try using **FontAwesome**. It contains a sort-icon (http://fontawesome.io/icon/sort/).

To do so, you would

1. need to include fontawesome:

   ```
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```
2. and then simply use the fontawesome-icon instead of the default-bootstrap-icons in your `th`'s:

   ```
    <th><b>#</b> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
   ```

Comment: `fa-sort-asc` and `fa-sort-desc` can be useful too when you want to show the direction =)

Comment: scotch.io had a good article I used to make custom sort arrows that flip in Angular. https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular

Comment: Now the ascending and descending arrows for font awesome are `fa-sort-up` and `fa-sort-down`

Comment: In Font Awesome v5.3.1 "fas fa-sort-up" and "fas fa-sort-down"

Answer (score 17):

Use this icons with bootstrap (glyphicon):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"></span>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_triangle-bottom&stacked=h

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_triangle-bottom&stacked=h

Comment: Not recommended. it will spoil the your UX

Comment: @AkshayPethani I dont understand your comment, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @kiltek I mean this is not recommended way to get sort icons. Instead you can use the <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i>

Comment: @AkshayPethani That makes no sense, in bootstrap 3 there is no font awesome. You only have glyphicon, no point pulling in a whole new icon pack just for sorting icons.

Comment: The **Glyphicons icon font** has been dropped from Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

**BOOTSTRAP 4**

> you can use a combination of
>
> - `fa-chevron-down, fa-chevron-up`
> - `fa-sort-down, fa-sort-up`

```
<th class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link py-0 pl-0 pr-1">
             Some Text OR icon
        </button>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
            <a href="?sort=asc" class="btn btn-xs btn-link p-0">
                <i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="?sort=desc" class="btn btn-xs btn-link p-0">
                <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
```